# How to store button information from previous activity, Android Studio Edition

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, I have an activity with 2 buttons marsPhoto and viewByDate. After the buttons are clicked they go to a new activity page where I want to take the name from the putExtra (Daily or Date) and printout Daily or Date in the TextView.  I only want to set the text to match the string for the button (which is Daily for intent2 clicked and Date for intent3 clicked).

> Activity 1

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.marsPhoto:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MARS.class);
            intent2.putExtra("Daily",1);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.viewByDate:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, MARS.class);
            intent3.putExtra("Date",2);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
    }
}
```

> Activity 2

```
TextView type;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mars);
    type = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.type);
    Intent i = getIntent();

    String s1 = i.getStringExtra("Daily");
    String s2 = i.getStringExtra("Date");

    type.setText(s1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the key for the passed `StringExtra` to something like `"button_text"` and set the value to the text you want to display, i.e. `"Date"` or `"Daily"`. There doesn't seem to be any meaning to the integer you are transferring.

Answer (score 0):

modify the first code to this

Activity 1

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.marsPhoto:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MARS.class);
        intent2.putExtra("dataSent","Daily");
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;
    case R.id.viewByDate:
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, MARS.class);
        intent3.putExtra("dataSent","Date");
        startActivity(intent3);
        break;
    }
}
```

Activity 2

```
   TextView type;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mars);
    type = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.type);
        String s1="";
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            s1 = "";
        } else {
            s1 = extras.getString("dataSent","");
        }
   
    type.setText(s1);
```

}